# Can you throw in the ball in soccer while twisted?

Tags: rules, football

Is it illegal to throw in a ball with the lower body  turned in one direction ( i e below waist)and the upper body in another? That is if I twist myself and try to throw in a ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a legal move as long as you face the field.

[Law 15](https://theifab.com/laws/chapter/35/section/115/) doesn't prohibit it:

> At the moment of delivering the ball, the thrower must:
>
> - stand facing the field of play
> - have part of each foot on the touchline or on the ground outside the
>   touchline
> - throw the ball with both hands from behind and over the head from the
>   point where it left the field of play